# Does 'enter' take the preposition 'into' or not?

Tags: prepositions

Does 'enter' take the preposition 'into' or not? 
For example: She entered into the main gates and walked along the avenue.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *enter* can be followed by the preposition *into*. But *to enter* and *to enter into* are commonly used in different contexts with differing meanings.

In general terms, *to enter* without the preposition *into* is used for entering physical spaces, locations or buildings. Examples:

> - She entered the park through a hole in the fence.
> - The vandal entered the school during the night.
> - They entered the city on horseback.

*To enter into*, on the other hand, is used for starting or joining something:

> - He entered into a discussion with the girl behind the bar.
> - She entered into the contract without considering the consequences.
> - The two countries entered into a close economic partnership.

But the usages are very often not clear-cut. So you will find references to *entering into a city* and *entering a war*.

In your particular example, however, *into* is not correct. You do not go *into* gates, you go *through* them *into* somewhere. So, your sentence needs to read something like:

> She entered the town through the main gates and walked along the
>   avenue.